# SQL compilation error: invalid identifier for TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) fields in Snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with 2 TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9) fields. When I try to add either of these to a WHERE clause I get a SQL compilation error: invalid identifier. If name either of these field in my SELECT statement I also get this error. If I perform a SELECT * the fields are available and return data.

Relatively new to Snowflake, what am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share the SQL?

Comment: Worked it out. For some reason the field is Case Sensitive...

Comment: they are only case sensitive if you put them in quotes, and then you can set a session variable to make quotes strings case insensitive, but then you can get bitten as they become upcase by default.. quotes are just a bad idea, and if you have columns that need quotes then it sounds like you have put your UI in the DB which is also a bad idea. Last point this is a bad quiestion, as it has not subtance.

Comment: Actually Simeon, it not a bad question, there are no such things as bad question. I just happen to be the end user for the data, so have no say in how the tables and data are structured. I am new to Snowflake SQL and am still coming across these differences from other platforms.Thanks for your constructive feedback!

Comment: You're right @NathWA, It isn't a bad question but it could be improved. When you're asking a question it helps to provide as much information as possible, in this case it would have helped if you had provided the SQL query you were running and the structure of the table.